# How to select angular npm package datetimepicker in ts file ?

Tags: angular, datetime, npm, attributes, getelementbyid

document.getElementById and document.querySelector are not returning any results ...
This is html element I'm trying to get and set new attribute at certain event

```
<datetime id="datePicker" [datepicker]="datePickerOptions" 
[(ngModel)]="treasury.date" name="date" [timepicker]="false" ></datetime>
```

Any idea how can i access this element in .ts file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it using @ViewChild ,and then loging the ViewChild because normal console.log isn't working on this kind of component . 
[good material to learn ViewChild in angular](https://alligator.io/angular/viewchild-access-component/)